# Whitelist outbound mail

Tags: email, whitelist

Is there a way to limit the list of mailadresses a user can send mail **to**, to a small whitelist of approved addresses?

The only option I can think of right now is a customized contact form, but I'm looking for a better way that is or can be integrated in an existing mailclient?

Comment: It is unclear about what kind of setup you are talking. A MTA (which), a firewall or mail gateway, a desktop system, a web mail client, ... ? I propose to close the question as too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Set up whatever mail server you use to filter mail based on destination. This is trivial.

For Postfix this is solved with the [check recipient access table](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_recipient_access) configuration directive, which lets you configure either a system wide, or per user allowed destinations. For different MTA's there's different options.